# Shifting and HTML div over with a set interval using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have images that are loading with content inside of them. Now, everytime the set interval counter is executed I want the div to animate to the left 500 px rather than just appearing and disappearing. I am using jquery. I have it now so that it appends to the content div.

```
function nextItem(){
    counter ++;
    $content.empty();
    if(counter <= 3){
        var $current = '<div id="item" style="background-image: url(' + images[counter].image + ');"><p id="title"> ' + images[counter].title + ' </p><p id="caption"> ' + images[counter].caption + ' </p></div>';
        var $next = '<div id="item" style="background-image: url(' + images[counter + 1].image + ')"><p id="title"> ' + images[counter + 1].title + ' </p><p id="caption"> ' + images[counter + 1].caption + ' </p></div>'
        $content.append($current);
        $content.append($next);
    }
    if(counter > 3){
        counter = 0;
        var $current = '<div id="item" style="background-image: url(' + images[counter].image + ');"><p id="title"> ' + images[counter].title + ' </p><p id="caption"> ' + images[counter].caption + ' </p></div>';
        var $next = '<div id="item" style="background-image: url(' + images[counter + 1].image + ')"><p id="title"> ' + images[counter + 1].title + ' </p><p id="caption"> ' + images[counter + 1].caption + ' </p></div>'
        $content.append($current);
        $content.append($next);
    }
}
```

I tried to write it like '

```
$content.append($current).animate({right:'400px'});
```

but it didnt work

Comment: *1st:* id should be unique use class instead .. it may not affect your code now but later it will .. *2nd:* did you tried `.animate({"margin-right":'400px'});`

Comment: **Note** `.append().animate()` will not work with the appended element it will work for `$content` .. so after change all `id="item"` to `class="item"` you can use `.append(....).find('.item:last').animate(.....)`